# ActiveRecord - Use Include together with Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**client.rb**

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to   :address
end
```

**address.rb**

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :state
    has_one :country
end
```

From `Client#show` I want to return a JSON containing the client details and its address. However, there are some fields in `address` that I don't want to return (like created_at, updated_at).

I have written this to render the JSON -

```
def show
   @client = Client.select("id, address_id").first
   render json: underscore_to_camel(@client.as_json(:include => :address))
end
```

Like I have used `select` for `Client` how can I use it for `Address`?

**Edit**

If I use `@client.as_json(include: {address: { except: [:created_at, :updated_at]}})` the resulting hash does not have `created_at`.

But when the query runs, it does a `select *` on `addresses`. Is there a way to do this so that the query itself selects only the columns required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `except` option of [***`as_json`***](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json)

```
render json: underscore_to_camel(@client.as_json(include: {address: { except: [:created_at, :updated_at]}}))
```

Comment: This does work. But it still fetches all the columns from the database. Is there a way we can restrict the columns at the database query level? Like `select`.

Comment: @mridula All the columns from which table?

Comment: @mridula can you post the rendered `json` here?

Comment: Sorry, I can't post the JSON right now. I can post it later. All the columns of the `addresses` table.

Comment: From the rails log:

`Client Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  id, address_id, name, default_language, main_phone, contact_person_name, contact_person_email, contact_person_phone, website, notes FROM "clients" ORDER BY "clients"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]`

`Address Load (19.9ms)  SELECT  "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]`

Comment: @mridula I meant the JSON response. Can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `only` option to select specific columns from your table

```
render json: underscore_to_camel(@client.as_json(include: {address: { only: [:address_column1, :address_column2, ...]}}))
```

replace your `column names` with `address_column1`, `address_column2` and so on.

Hope this helps